# Куда записать данные о персоне, чтобы можно было обратится к ним по индексу?

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть данные о персоне, имя фамилия год дисциплина и т.д. И нужно записать их в что-то наподобие массива, чтобы при обращении через индекс персоны вывелись его данные.

Comment: зачем подобие, если есть массив?

Comment: Хорошо. Как можно в массив добавить данные о персоне и чтобы по ходу кода можно было увеличивать длину массива?

Comment: `чтобы по ходу кода можно было увеличивать длину массива?` почему бы все требования сразу не писать в вопрос? Вам нужен `List<Person>`

Comment: [Array.Resize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.7.2) например